How to log using serilog to elasticsearch with Elastic.Serilog.Sinks in .net application
I want to log to elasticsearch using serilog.
I have added Elastic.Serilog.Sinks package to my application.
But there is no way to pass username and password while configuring serilog elasticsearch config.
My assumption is that I would need to pass log index name, url, username, password while configuring serilog with elasticsearch sink.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/dotnet/current/serilog-data-shipper.html
Above url has example to configure using url. Also, there is no index name.
Is log index name and data stream name same ?
How to pass username and password while configuring serilog elasticsearch configuration ?

Have you gone through this ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elastic.Serilog.Sinks#:~:text=.WriteTo.ElasticCloud(%22cloudId%22%2C%20%22cloudUser%22%2C%20%22cloudPass%22%2C%20opts%20%3D%3E

Yes, but it doesn't mention how to pass username and password while configuring.

You could install Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch and try this
var settings = new ElasticsearchClientSettings(new Uri("https://10.96.5.5:9200"))
        .CertificateFingerprint("xxx")
        .Authentication(new BasicAuthentication("elastic", "xxx"));

var esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(settings);

var esOptions = new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(esClient.Transport)
{
    BootstrapMethod = BootstrapMethod.Failure,
};

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(esOptions)
    .CreateLogger();

Or this:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
 .WriteTo.Elasticsearch([new Uri("https://10.96.5.5:9200")], opts =>
 {
     opts.BootstrapMethod = BootstrapMethod.Failure;
 }, transport =>
 {
     transport.CertificateFingerprint("xxx");
     transport.Authentication(new BasicAuthentication("elastic", "xxx"));
 })
 .CreateLogger();

